# Elastic/NEST will not handle null values

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am currently limited to NEST v2.4.6.

I have objects with attributes that can sometimes be null and must be persisted with those null attributes.

According to the documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/modifying-default-serializer.html#_modifying_settings_using_serializerfactory

This should allow me to serialize Null values.
Unfortunately, once setting this up, all my ElasticDB queries start to return nothing.

This is confusing as when I put the

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
```

attribute, it works fine.

I obviously however would like to enable this globally.

This is what my implementation looks like:

```
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticInstanceAddress"]));
    var connection = new HttpConnection();
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, connection,
        new SerializerFactory((s, values) =>
    {
        s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
    }));
```

An example NEST query that suddenly starts to return nothing after the `NullValueHandling` is enabled on the serializer is as below:

```
var dog = _client.Get<Dog>(query.DogName).Source;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why should your object be persisted with null values? Persisted or not, the value should be `null` when deserialized back from `_source` because the field is either missing or actually set to `null`. In any case, it should work by default. Checking for null in a query can be done with an Exists Query, see : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Comment: It's legacy code that relies on nulls on the object. I don't need to check for nulls. I need to be able to serialize and deserialize nulls. As stated in the OP, setting the NullValueHandling.Include option on the JSON serializer works only when used as an attribute rather than the usual global way. I don't think the exists query is relevant here if I can't deserialize anything in the first place with the setting in place.

Comment: @Kyanite a `null` value on `_source` will deserialize to a `null` property on a type, unless you have some special handling in deserialization. The end result is that `null` on `_source` for a property and no property on `_source` is the same when deserialized into an instance of a CLR type. Do you need to differentiate between these for some other reason?

Comment: @Kyanite NEST serialize and deserialize `null` values by default. You're fetching a document by Id passing in `query.DogName` that doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Kyanite it's not clear in the OP what works and what doesn't.